# Devise logged in root route rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, devise

Heyya **guys**.
So i thought about this coolio idea, if you are logged in then you get some sort of dashboard, else you get an information/login/sign up page.. So how do i do that..

I mostly wants to do this in Routes = not something like

```
def index
  if current_user.present?
    render :action => 'logged_in'
  else
    render :action => 'logged_out'
  end
end
```

thanks in advance!

/ Oluf Nielsen

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Think you may have been looking for this:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#show"
end

root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

Note: it's authenticate*d*

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i wanted to do!

Comment: This did not work for me, as I wanted the not-logged in route to point to something else as sessions#new. Shayne's answer however works in those cases and was the solution for me...clarifying: if you set the seccond root :to entry to anything else than devise/sessions#new it will still redirect an unauthenticated user to sessions#new.

Comment: I know I'm late, but if you use ```authenticated :user``` (notice the "d") it should work as expected

Comment: From what I have gotten, you don't need the last line. `authenticate` will redirect you if you're not logged in.

Comment: Super useful! I didn't find this in the Devise docs, and it's an excellent, clean solution.

Comment: For **Rails 4.0** you have to make sure you have unique names for the path helpers, like `root to: "dashboard#show", as: :authenticated_root`. Otherwise the authenticated root and the normal root route end up having the same name for their path helpers, which Rails 4.0 no longer allows.

Comment: Careful to make sure you don't use the plural of your model either, that won't work.

Answer (score 25):

I too wanted this in my app, here's what I came up with.

```
MyCoolioApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'users#dashboard', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  get "/" => 'users#dashboard', :as => "user_root"

  # ..
end
```

In Rails 3 you can use [Request Based Contraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) to dynamically map your `root` route. The solution above works for the Devise authentication gem but can be modified to support your own implementation.

With the above `root_path` or `/` will route to a `WelcomeController#index` action for un-authenticated requests. When a user is logged in the same `root_path` will route to `UsersController#dashboard`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How would I write routing tests for this using RSpec, though? Doesn't look like `authenticate?` is available in the test environment? Would appreciate any guidance... thanks.

Comment: I had to add a scope to get it working: request.env["warden"].authenticate?(:scope => :user)

Comment: also, the new devise has a cool new method called authenticated, which does this for you

Answer (score 21):

I have the same problem and I solved it with this:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "wathever#index"
end
unauthenticated :user do
  devise_scope :user do 
    get "/" => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked, but instead of get "/" => ... I did root to: "devise/sessions#new" and it worked, probably the same thing - thank you!

Comment: Could you also explain what "authenticated" and "unauthenticated" do?

Comment: The first will match when an authenticated user exists, while the second will match when he not to exist.

Answer (score 4):

are you using devise's before filters?

```
class FooController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
...
```

Why don't you try altering the default login views so they have the info/login/signup infos you want.

Comment: That's not what i want to..
i want to make two >> root :to => "welcome#index" << - or something like that, when you're not logged in, and something like >> root :to => "dashboard#index"<< - When you are logged in..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using in my application layout file right now. Haven't broken it out into partials yet:

```
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <a href="/profile"><%= current_user.email %></a> | 
                <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> |
                <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: as i said up in the other one, "That's not what i want to.. i want to make two >> root :to => "welcome#index" << - or something like that, when you're not logged in, and something like >> root :to => "dashboard#index"<< - When you are logged in.."

Comment: In that case, write a before_filter in your default root method (the one pointing to welcome#index) that checks if the user is logged in and if so, redirect_to dashboard#index. It doesn't even need to be a before_filter, you can do it straight in the index method.

Comment: well, that's what BaroqueBobcat wrote to, so if theres no else way to make it i accepting he's solution. Thanx for the help :-)!