# How do I map Rails default root to the login page using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, root

The default root page of my app needs to be the login page.

If I do this (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791096/devise-logged-in-root-route-rails-3)):

```
root :to => "devise/sessions#new
```

I get:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-06 10:36:38 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed   in 0ms

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (AbstractController::ActionNotFound):
```

I've also tried to overwrite the `Devise::SessionsController` to look like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
  end
end
```

In routes I have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

**EDIT** `rake routes` show:

```
 ...
 new_user_session     GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
 user_session         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
 destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
 root                        /(.:format)                 {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
 ...
```

Using devise 1.1.7 with Rails 3.

Comment: Could you show us your `rake routes` output?

Comment: Added relevant section of `rake routes` to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need that the login page is the default even if the user is already logged in?

If thats not the case you can just point to some controller.

In your routes:

```
map.root :controller => :your_controller
```

And then require that the user is authenticated:
In your_controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

That will redirect the user to the login form except if he/she is already logged in.