# Different '/' root path for users depending if they are authenticated (using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I'm writing a rails app in which I have an Editor and a Publication model. I'm using devise for editors authentication and, since an editor can't do anything as guest, I wrote a custom layout to use for the login page and I want that a guest user can see only the login page.

Now I'm trying to achieve the following behavior in my app but unsuccessfully:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rails'

describe "Authentication" do

  describe "when logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      @editor = Factory(:editor, :password => 'secret')
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'Login', :with => @editor.login
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'secret'
      click_button 'Sign in'
      page.should have_content('Signed in successfully.')
    end

    it "getting / should render publication page with no redirection" do
      visit '/'
      page.should_not have_content('Login')
      page.should have_content('Publications')
      # assert that there is no redirection
      page.current_path.should == '/'
    end

    it "visits the sign_in page should redirect to /" do
      visit '/editors/sign_in'
      page.should have_content('Publications')
      page.current_path.should == '/'
    end

  end

  describe "when not logged in" do
    it "getting / should not display the sign in warning" do
      visit '/'
      # I want to get rid of this message
      page.should_not have_content('You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.')
    end

    it "getting / should not redirect to the sign_in default page" do
      visit '/'
      page.should have_content('Login')
      # assert that there is no redirection
      page.current_path.should == '/'
    end

    it "getting the the sign_in default path works" do
      visit '/editors/sign_in'
      page.should have_content('Login')
      page.current_path.should == '/editors/sign_in'
    end

    it "login works and redirect me to the publications page (with /)" do
      @editor = Factory(:editor, :password => 'secret')
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'Login', :with => @editor.login
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'secret'
      click_button 'Sign in'
      page.should have_content('Signed in successfully.')
      page.current_path.should == '/'
      page.should have_content('Publications')
    end
  end
end
```

The main issue is that I want to get rid of 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.' message when a guest user visit '/'.

I tried with hints taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791096/devise-logged-in-root-route-rails-3/3846685#3846685) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/974#issuecomment-975797) but with no luck.

Any hint on how implement this with devise?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you could do with creating a namespace... Have you considered this?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This post](http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/) explain how to achieve that:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "main#dashboard"
end

root :to => "main#index"
```

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1147) which implement this with some technical details

Comment: I followed his directions, but got the errors about duplicate routes that @wildmonkey alludes to.  Specifying `as:` was an important missing step for me.

Answer (score 30):

I think you should use something like that

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'users#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

since rails4 doesn't allow routes with same name you **need** to specify *as:*

Answer (score 6):

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'home#index', :as => :authenticated_root
end
root :to => redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

Straight from the horse's mouth at the [How to's for the devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages). :D

Answer (score 2):

Also because of you need to name these root paths in Rails 4 you might find that it is annoying when you want to just use root_path on *say your logo* to take you back to the dashboard or homepage respectively. I just created helpers in the ApplicationHelper that solves that easily.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def root_path
    if user_signed_in?
      authenticated_root_path
    else
      unauthenticated_root_path
    end
  end

  def root_url
    if user_signed_in?
      authenticated_root_url
    else
      unauthenticated_root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this issue was really frustrating for me as well.

Ultimately I ended up just hiding the flash message on the sessions#new page. Not a great solution at all since sometimes you /do/ want that message to show up..

I gave up after a while, but I wonder if you could use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791096/devise-logged-in-root-route-rails-3/3846685#3846685), but set some flag inside that lambda and have a before_filter in your sessions controller that empties flash if it's present. Something like...

```
#routes
=> 'users#dashboard', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["skip_flash"] = true; r.env["warden"].authenticate? }


#sessions_controller.rb
before_filter :only=>[:new] do
  flash[:notice] = nil if request.env["skip_flash"]
  request.env["skip_flash"] = false
end
```

I'm not too familiar with how the routes constraint and the request object work.. but just an idea. This would turn off the flash message only when you're trying to access the "/" and not other pages..

I hope somebody has a nice solution!

Comment: Me too, I don't like this kind of solution.