# Active Admin authentication conflicting with User authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin, warden

[Active Admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) is a gem used for having an admin dashboard in your application. It uses Devise for logging in users and creates a separate `admin_user` model for the admins. My application already uses devise and has its users as the `user` model. Ever since I started using the active admin gem, in my routes file the following line keeps resolving to home#index and not users#dashboard even when my user is logged in. This used to work fine earlier where logged in users were taken to users#dashboard as the root url.

```
root :to => 'users#dashboard', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }
root :to => 'home#index'
```

What is happening is that the `.authenticate?` is checking for the `admin_user` (belonging to Active Admin) being logged in or not but not my `user` model which is what I need to check for, so when I am logged in to active admin interface, my site root becomes users#dashboard instead without checking if the `user` is logged in or not. How can I make `.authenticate?` check for the `user` being logged in and not `admin_user` ?

Any help or clues will be very much appreciated

Comment: It actually seems like I am getting this issue due to Active Admin and the fact that it uses Devise. Logging in to the active admin interface affects the behavior such that the app attempts to take every user to the dashboard if the active admin is logged in and every user to the home#index if active admin is logged out, both regardless of if the general user itself is logged in or not

Comment: Any help or clues will be very much appreciated

Comment: the Current User section in config/initializers/active_admin.rb

Comment: Actually that is already set to `config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user` which is different from `current_user` used throughout the app. Thing is, Devise uses Warden, and the command above I am using in the Routes file is dependent on Warden. If there was another command I could use which was more specific to which user to use, it would make it so much easier :/

Comment: redirect_to root_path unless warden.user.is_admin?

Comment: trying to figure the syntax for that. but very likely that devise's scope feature needs to be utilized here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to solve this. The issue was related to Devise expecting a single user model in the application. Here is how to fix it.

In the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file, add:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

and

```
config.default_scope = :user #or whichever is your regular default user model
```

thats it, warden checks the :user for being logged in and not :admin_user

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `get "/"`? You should remove it. I'm using a definition pretty similar to yours and works fine with me. Use just:

```
root :to => 'users#dashboard', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it still always takes me to home#index. It seems like `lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }` always returns false for me regardless of the fact the the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you can try something like

```
root :to => proc { |env| [ 302, {'Location'=> env["warden"].authenticate? ? "users/dashboard" : "/home" }, [] ] }
```

Comment: I tried using `root :to => proc { |env| [ 302, {'Location'=> env["warden"].authenticate? ? "users/dashboard" : "/home/index" }, [] ] }` but it tries to always take me to /home/index regardless of the fact that the user is logged in or not. Im suspecting something is up with the authenticate? command, maybe always resulting in false

Comment: I am not familiar with Warden, but you can look deep into it's source to implement `authenticate?` in your proc. Or `env["warden"]` returns not what expected.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
constraint = lambda { |request| request.env["warden"].authenticate? and request.env['warden'].user.instance_of?(AdminUser) }
```